# Roadnetwork_merging

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, line, network, road

I have a shapefile of a road network which has two lines to represent the two-way directions.

My attribute consists of "fromnode", "Tonode", "length", "One-way" (every cell has a value of one here, as every line is one-way).

I want to merge them into one line and the column "one-way" get two values (1 for one direction, 2 for the opposite).

How can i do this using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: This question needs some clarification.  Do you want to create a new field in your feature class and concatenate the string values from the other fields into a new field?  I also dont understand what you mean by 1 for 1 direction and 2 for the opposite.   Do you mean if you had a FC with values FromNode 10, ToNode 20, ength 50, and oneway 1 .  You would want two new columns and in Column 1 you want 1 10 20 50 (1 way , from node 10 to 20 and length of 50), and in Column 2 you would want 2 20 10 50 (other direction, from node 20 to node 10, length 50) ??

Comment: at the moment, i have two lines for one segment. One going to one direction and the second to the other. I need to merge these two lines of the segment to one, so i will get one column showing the directions. How i merge these lines into one (demonstrating as well that its one line with two-way directions)?

Comment: Some screenshots of what you've got and an example of what you want may be useful here.  Can you please [edit] your question to include some?